# What item combinations give you health?

Tags: runescape

Apparently there are some items in the game that give you health, and can be consumed with other health giving items. For example shark sarabrew, or sharp chocolate bomb. Are there more combinations? Are there cheap alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 combinations. There are:

1. Shark/Rocktail - Sara Brew
2. Shark/Monkfish - Chocolate Bomb
3. Shark/Rocktail/Monkfish - Karambwan

There are also Barbarian potions that when consumed heal as well (20 hp for non Eoc/ 200 for Eoc).

Probably the cheapest method is the Shark to sara brew. Then regain your skills by using a combat potion NOT a super restore.